# Content of UITableView Cell is disappearing on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've faced with very common problem with disappearing cells.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WorkOut *previousWorkOut = nil;
    if (indexPath.row > 0)
    {
        previousWorkOut = [self.currentDayArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];
    }
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    WorkOutCell *cell = nil;
    WorkOut *currentWorkOut = [self.currentDayArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell = [[WorkOutCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *workoutLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0, 0, 180, 160}];
    CGPoint workOutPoint = CGPointMake(220.0f, 25.0f);
    cell.workOutName = workoutLabel;
    cell.workOutName.center = workOutPoint;
    cell.workOutName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.workOutName.textColor = kiOSColor;
    cell.workOutName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:20.0f];
    cell.workOutName.text = currentWorkOut.workoutName;
    cell.workOutName.numberOfLines = 3;
    cell.workOutName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    cell.workOutName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.workOutName];

    UILabel *timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0, 0, 160, 160}];
    CGPoint timePoint = CGPointMake(40.0f, 25.0f);
    cell.timeLabel = timeLabel;
    cell.timeLabel.center = timePoint;
    cell.timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.timeLabel.textColor = kIOSRedColor;
    cell.timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:45.0f];
    if (![currentWorkOut.workoutTime isEqualToString:previousWorkOut.workoutTime])
    {
        cell.timeLabel.text = currentWorkOut.workoutTime;
    }
    cell.timeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    cell.timeLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(cell.timeLabel.transform, 0.4f, 0.4f);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.timeLabel];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    if (![currentWorkOut.workoutTime isEqualToString:previousWorkOut.workoutTime])
    {
        UIView *upperLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){50, 2, 320, 1}];
        upperLine.backgroundColor = kiOSLightColor;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:upperLine];
    }
    else
    {
        UIView *upperLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){60, 2, 320, 1}];
        upperLine.backgroundColor = kiOSLightColor;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:upperLine];
}

    UIView *separatorLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){55, 80, 320, 1}];
    cell.upperLine = separatorLine;
    cell.upperLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    cell.upperLine.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.upperLine];
    NSString *w = currentWorkOut.workoutDescription;
     NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:16.0f] forKey: NSFontAttributeName];
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(255, 295);
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [w boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize
                                                     options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                  attributes:d context:nil].size;

    UILabel *workoutDescription = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){50, 85, 255, expectedLabelSize.height}];
    cell.workOutDescription = workoutDescription;
    cell.workOutDescription.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.workOutDescription.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.workOutDescription.text = [currentWorkOut.workoutDescription stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    cell.workOutDescription.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    cell.workOutDescription.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.workOutDescription.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:16.0f];
    cell.workOutDescription.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.workOutDescription];
    return cell;
}
```

And method for updating cell where I`m changing parametres of cell:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.isOpen == YES && [self.selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        WorkOutCell *cell = (WorkOutCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^
         {
             cell.timeLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(cell.timeLabel.transform, 0.4f, 0.4f);
             CGPoint timePoint = CGPointMake(40.0f, 25.0f);
             cell.timeLabel.center = timePoint;

             CGPoint workoutPoint = CGPointMake(220.0f, 25.0f);
             cell.workOutName.center = workoutPoint;
             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:0.7f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^
              {
                  cell.workOutDescription.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
                  cell.upperLine.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
              }
                              completion:^ (BOOL finished)
              {
              }];
         }
                         completion:^ (BOOL finished)
         {
             self.isOpen = NO;
             [self.table beginUpdates];
             [self.table endUpdates];
         }];
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
    //
    //...
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

I've tried `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` but it did not work for me.

Updated code for:

- creation of cell
- updating cell state, look

Comment: What do you mean "disappears"? and what does this line means :cell.workOutName = workoutLabel; ?

Comment: workOutName is UILabel class member of WorkOutCell. I have several animations that are changing look of labels, i.e opacity. User touches specific cell and it is expanding and label with text is shown, but after scrolling (cell goes out of screen and back) cell has default state and all changes are disappeared (i.e. expanded state and label with text)

Comment: If by disappear you mean, changes that were made to cell disappear, that is pretty normal. Each time a cell is displayed (even when it has been displayed before), cellForRowAtIndexPath is called and each time you initialize your cell in it.

Comment: Could you put the complete method including "adding content" part ? And also as you mention specific behavior when user touching the cell please put that implementation too. As you may know cells are removed and redrawn when they disappear so you need to make sure that you "redraw" it correctly.

Comment: Added code for creation of cell, its update according to touch.

Comment: Fixed) Added temporary variable (class property) to store open cell and on `building` new cell in  cellForRowAtIndexPath: checking if it exists (open and what`s index path of it)